# select top 1 nhibernate oracle

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

i use nhibernate that connected with oracle.

what is wrong with my syntax :

```
 string requeteString = @"select distinct reponse1 from 
                                     (select reponse2 from CAMPAGNE reponse2 where reponse2.TEl = :tel  and reponse2.EXECUTE.ID = :IdExecute order by reponse2.ReponseLEVEL desc) reponse1
                                      where rownum = 1";

 IQuery requete = this.CreateQuery(requeteString);
```

i got error:
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException was caught
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=Une exception de type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' a été levée. near line 2, column 37
  Source=NHibernate

Comment: your outer query is not referencing the same name for your field in the subquery  select distinct reponse1 from 
                                     (select reponse2

Comment: thanks you for your respond, could you be more specific please

Comment: select distinct reponse1 from  (select reponse2 they dont match

Answer (score 1):

`CreateQuery` is for HQL, not SQL. You need to use `CreateSQLQuery` instead.

Comment: but i use HQL, as you can see on my query

Comment: What is rownum in HQL, then? rownum is an Oracle concept.